# Azure Create Resource Monitoring Webhooks using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-monitoring

In Azure is it possible to create an alert, with a webhook, if any of my resource goes up or down(not service, but resource)? I see many alert conditions but none of them do plain up/down monitoring.

Is it possible to create these alerts (with a webhook) programatically using REST API(without logging into Azure portal), once i get the required authorization? Currently I am unable to find any create alert REST API

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to do this.

The REST API provided by Azure for monitoring can be used to create new Action Groups and create new Alerts.

The document here gives more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/actiongroups

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertrules/createorupdate